# Looking for a way to find cursor position within excel worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, cursor, position, vsto

I know about System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position, but this does not give the cursor position within the excel worksheet. I am looking for a way to get the cursor position within the worksheet, similar to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Shape.Left

All help is appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

By cursor position, do you mean the position of the selected cell in the worksheet, or do you mean the position of the text insertion point when you are editing a cell?

If the former, you can use `Selection.Address`.  For the latter, I do not know the answer.

Comment: I don't mean either one. I mean the position of the cursor icon (as in the little arrow that moves when the mouse moves) within the worksheet regardless of whether or not I am editing a cell, formatting a shape or whatever.

Comment: @user3642682 I am fairly certain that the Excel automation object model doesn't support this.  The only MouseMove event belongs to the Chart class, so that's not particularly helpful.  If you're looking for information about where the user *clicks* as opposed to where the mouse pointer is *hovering*, then the Sheet.BeforeDoubleClick and Sheet.BeforeRightClick events might help.  For a plain click, you can use the SelectionChange event.  I suspect that these won't be adequate for your needs, however.  If you describe the problem you're trying to solve, you might get a better response.

Comment: Hey, ok, basically, I would like the user to be able to click on a rectangle shape, and then I would like to add a line shape oriented so that its end is as close as possible to the location that the user clicked but still flush with the rectangle. I figured that I would read in the cursor position. Then, do some calculations and add the line. I just cannot figure out how to get the cursor position with respect to the left side of column A and the top of the worksheet.

Comment: @user3642682 As you may know, `Shape` is the interface for dealing with shapes (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.shape(v=office.15).aspx), but there's no API for responding to user input.  There's probably some low-level way to get at this information through the windows message loop, but I suspect that would be more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: can you expand on that? what do you mean by the windows message loop? I dont think I can continue without getting this info.

Comment: @user3642682 Here be demons.  The windows message loop is the very low-level construct that the operating system uses to communicate with applications, including information about mouse moves and clicks.  It would most likely be very difficult to translate these mouse coordinates (relative to the application window) to coordinates you would use in the object model (relative to the worksheet).  A better solution might be to give your user buttons that would allow them to move the line up and down, indirectly.